# How to replace all occurrence of particular nested tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get the html file tags data without nested tags (prefer : BeautifulSoup base solution) but regex will also work
eg:

```
`<li><p>HELLO1</p></li >  <li>HELLO2</li><p>HELLO3</p>`
```

answer

```
HELLO1 HELLO2 HELLO3
```

I tried to use regex but didn't find how to use for soup object
 str(soup).replace("< li > < p >","< p >")

```
tags = soup.find_all(['p','li'])
it returns:
< p >HELLO1< /p >,
HELLO1 ,
HELLO2 ,
HELLO3
```

if there is li and p tags are nested result should show only one occurrence or one nested tag should be removed.
eg:if < li >< p >XYZ< /p >< /li >
       it should becomes < li >XYZ< /li >

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.get_text()` method:

```
data = '''<li><p>HELLO1</p></li >  <li>HELLO2</li><p>HELLO3</p>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

print(soup.get_text(separator=' ', strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
HELLO1 HELLO2 HELLO3
```